# Is set based possible instead of cursor loop in this scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Current code:

```
DECLARE thisLoop CURSOR FOR  
SELECT IdOld, IdNew  
FROM @fieldNewOld;  

OPEN thisLoop;  

FETCH NEXT FROM thisLoop INTO @fIdOld, @fIdNew;  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN

UPDATE dbo.mel
      SET melCode = REPLACE(melCode, '_' + CONVERT(varchar(50),@fIdOld), '_' + CONVERT(varchar(50),@fIdNew))
      where fID = (select IdNew from @newForm) and melCode LIKE ('%_'  + CONVERT(varchar(50), @fIdOld) + '%')

    FETCH NEXT FROM thisLoop INTO @fIdOld, @fIdNew 
END;  

CLOSE thisLoop;  
DEALLOCATE thisLoop;
```

There is more going on around this, but basically I'm making a copy of a data set.  @fieldNewOld contains the old id's and new id's.  melCode in dbo.mel contains code written (in a proprietary language) that can reference all of the old id's.  It would be referenced something like "myVar_1234" where 1234 would be one of the old id's.  When copying, I'm wanting to replace all of the old id's with the new id's in melCode.

I can do it with the cursor loop shown above, but it is VERY slow when there is a large data set.  I've also tried the code below, but if there is more than one old id in melCode, it will try to update the same row multiple times and throw an error:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.mel b
   USING @fieldNewOld a
      ON b.fID = (select IdNew from @newForm) and b.melCode LIKE ('%_' + CONVERT(varchar(50), a.IdOld) + '%')
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE 
      SET b.melCode = REPLACE(b.melCode, '_' + CONVERT(varchar(50),a.IdOld), '_' + CONVERT(varchar(50),a.IdNew));
```

Is there any way to accomplish this in a set based fashion, or am I stuck with the slowness of the cursor loop?

Example Data:

@fieldNewOld

```
IdOld | IdNew
1234 | 5678
1235 | 5679
1236 | 5680
```

melCode (all of this would be in one row)

```
userok("My variable: " + myVar_1234)
myVar_1234 = "this is a test"
newVar_1236 = "here is some more data"
```

After copying I would want melCode to look like this:

```
userok("My variable: " + myVar_5678)
myVar_5678 = "this is a test"
newVar_5680 = "here is some more data"
```

Comment: You can use `JOIN`.

Comment: Hi Phil! Could you please provide us with an example input, and the desired output/state?

Comment: @Cowthulhu example input and desired output added, thanks!

Comment: As a rule, you can (and should) always use set based logic unless you are calling another stored procedure in a loop. And even then, it should only be if system stored procedure is being called.

Comment: Be wary with `LIKE` and wild card matching. `%` will match a bunch o' characters, and (fun fact!) `_` will match 1 (one) character. So, `LIKE '%_'` will quite probably not do what you think it does. Work in escape characters: `LIKE '%[_]'`... but test it a lot, to make sure it works as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JOINs in an UPDATE.

```
UPDATE m
SET melCode = REPLACE(melCode, '_' + CONVERT(varchar(50),IdOld), '_' + CONVERT(varchar(50),fIdNew))
FROM dbo.mel m
JOIN @fieldNewOld fno ON m.melCode LIKE ('%_'  + CONVERT(varchar(50), IdOld) + '%')
where fID = (select IdNew from @newForm) ;
```

This seems like you have a composite value in melCode. My suggestion would be to split the value into 2 or more columns and have melCode as a computed column.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an update with `JOIN` of your final table and table variables:

```
UPDATE m
SET m.melCode = REPLACE(m.melCode, '_' + CONVERT(varchar(50), f.IdOld), 
                        '_' + CONVERT(varchar(50), f.IdNew))
FROM dbo.mel m
JOIN @fieldNewOld f 
  ON m.melCode LIKE ('%_'  + CONVERT(varchar(50), f.IdOld) + '%')
JOIN @newForm n 
  ON m.fID = n.IdNew
```

---

Since you need to update the same text multiple times, consider wrapping above in an iterative update running across the number of rows in `fieldNewOld` IDs:

```
DECLARE @Counter INT
DECLARE @ID_Count INT

SET @Counter = 0
SET @ID_Count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @fieldNewOld)

WHILE @Counter <= @ID_Count

BEGIN
    UPDATE m
    SET m.melCode = REPLACE(m.melCode, '_' + CONVERT(varchar(50), f.IdOld), 
                            '_' + CONVERT(varchar(50), f.IdNew))
    FROM dbo.mel m
    JOIN @fieldNewOld f 
      ON m.melCode LIKE ('%_'  + CONVERT(varchar(50), f.IdOld) + '%')
    JOIN @newForm n 
      ON m.fID = n.IdNew 

    SET @Counter += 1
END
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/VQHUN78101)

Comment: Based on the example data I entered above, the code you provided only updates one of the id's but not multiple.  So, in the example above, myVar_1234 would be changed to myVar_5678, but newVar_1236 does not change to newVar_5680 using the code you provided.

Comment: @Phil where do you get that idea from? What you said is not true.

Comment: @LuisCazares I just ran the code, and it only updated one variable.  Maybe I'm missing something.  I'll try again.

Comment: @Phil There's nothing on Parfait's code or mine that would limit the rows updated to one.

Comment: @LuisCazares There is only one row of data that needs updating, so that is not the issue.  The problem is that the single row of data contains multiple references to multiple id's and those all need to be updated to reflect the new id's.  Using the join code provided, this `userok("My variable: " + myVar_1234)
myVar_1234 = "this is a test"
newVar_1236 = "here is some more data"` turned into this `userok("My variable: " + myVar_5678)
myVar_5678 = "this is a test"
newVar_1236 = "here is some more data"`

Comment: @Phil do the other non-updated rows align to `WHERE` conditions? See the `SELECT` version of `UPDATE` query: `SELECT m.melCode, f.IdNew, f.IdOld, n.IdNew As newForm_IdNew FROM dbo.mel m JOIN @fieldNewOld f ON m.melCode LIKE ('%_'  + CONVERT(varchar(50), f.IdOld) + '%') JOIN @newForm n 
ON m.fID = n.IdNew`.

Comment: Also with this simple [example](https://rextester.com/KTJJ57976), I cannot recreate the single row updating and not other rows on an `UPDATE...JOIN`. As you can see with before and after `SELECT` statements, ALL rows following the `JOIN` logic updates to SAME values (i.e., max score of each subject).

Comment: @Parfait I put together the code [here](https://rextester.com/JFXW56474) There is literally only one row in dbo.mel, and that is the row that needs to be updated with all of the new id's.

Comment: From that example, then what is your desired result? Add more rows to `dbo.mel` for each row in `@fieldNewOld`? Add more text to the one value?

Comment: @Parfait I want to update the row in `dbo.mel` to replace any of the old id's with the new id's from `@fieldNewOld`.

Comment: @Phil, see update with demo suggesting an iterative `UPDATE` for each row of `@fieldNewOld` using a `WHILE` loop.